How to implement Sobel kernels in 3D
wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator describes how to construct the 3D sobel kernel in the z direction but does not say how we are supposed to construct the 3D (not 2D!) Sobel kernels in the 2 other (x and y) directions...
Can you describe them i.e. what 2D matrix goes into each of the 3 channels for the x and y discrete derivatives in 3D? And explain why if possible.
I mean, it is not clear if i can simply plug a 2D Sobel x or y derivative in the middle channel then do a 3D convolution (that's the way i would do it "intuitively")... but not really sure...
